# how to store google map data in a mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, json

I am facing problem in storing data like distance,duration,route_info into   my database mysql. I am coding using eclipse luna and connected with mysql database.my database structure are 
         Trip(trip_id,source_addr,dest_addr)
         Route(route_id,trip_id,route_info,distance,duration)
how can i insert data into my tables,i am really expecting a help from the  community. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10pt;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var source, destination; 
        var directionsDisplay;              // The whole map rendering or displaying.

        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();  // For Availing the Direction Services provided by APIs

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {              //  This acts as a pageload Function    
            new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtSource'));
            new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtDestination'));
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
        });

        function GetRoute() {
            var kolkata = new google.maps.LatLng(22.7383075, 88.454424);  // Center of the Map
            var mapOptions = {              // Setting the View of the Map
                zoom: 7,
                center: kolkata
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);   // Variable for map view

            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);                              // Map view

            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('dvPanel'));  //Panel View

            //------------------------------DIRECTIONS AND ROUTE------------------------------------------------------

            source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
            destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;

            var request =                        // variable request
        {                                   // DirectionsService
                origin: source,
                destination: destination,
        provideRouteAlternatives: true,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {                  // RouteService
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });

            //-----------------------------DISTANCE AND DURATION----------------------------------------------------

            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();          // Different Services Provided by APIs
            service.getDistanceMatrix({
                origins: [source],
                destinations: [destination],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
            }, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                    var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;    //  Distance Calculation From data provide by APIs
                    var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;      //  Duration Calculation From data provide by APIs
                    var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");         // This Variable is for Fetching the Routes distance and displaying it on web page.
                    dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
                    dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
                    dvDistance.innerHTML += "Duration:" + duration;

                } else {
                    alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
                }
            });
        }                            

    </script>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                Source:
                <input type="text" id="txtSource"  style="width: 200px" />
                &nbsp; Destination:
                <input type="text" id="txtDestination" style="width: 200px" />
                <br />
                <input type="button" value="Get Route" onclick="GetRoute()" />
                <hr />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div id="dvDistance">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="dvMap" style="width: 800px; height: 500px">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="dvPanel" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried something? you want to save javascript variables to your backend?

Comment: yes ,i want to store the data which are there in the variable into my database.I am coding in java using eclipse luna and for backend i have mysql. i want to store those data which i mentioned on my problem. earlier i ahve tried ajax code but that did'nt help

Comment: To have more responses, I strongly suggest you to edit your question to ask simply how to save javascript variable to java. I think the fact that it is data from google map or that you are using Luna doesn't really matter for your problem

Comment: how can i store those variables into my database created.?